# Trying to print a table inside a for

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list inside a for and I'm doing this way:

```
for i in PSOE_data:
   if i[0] + i[1] + i[2] != 0:
        newList.append(i)

PSOE_list = PrettyTable(["Digital Chanel", "State", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"])
PSOE_list.align["Digital Chanel"] = "c" # Alinhamento pela esquerda
PSOE_list.padding_width = 1 # Espaçamento entre colunas (default)
PSOE_list.add_row([newList[i][3], newList[i][4], newList[i][0], newList[i][1], newList[i][2]])
print PSOE_list
```

But there is traceback that says:

```
    PSOE_list.add_row([newList[i][3], newList[i][4], newList[i][0], newList[i][1], newList[i][2]])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

How can I deal with that?
By the way, I'm using PrettyTable package.

Thank you!

Comment: What is POSE_data , what is POSE_list?

Comment: PSOE_data ----> [[0, 0, 0.0, 17, 2], [0, 0, 0.0, 25, 2], [0, 1, 0.017646, 11, 1], [0, 1, 0.028056, 10, 1], [0, 1, 0.028056, 12, 1], [0, 1, 1.032746, 10, 0], [0, 1, 1.032746, 12, 0], [0, 1, 1.091776, 11, 0]]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking some information... Do you want to print your list? If that is the case, maybe my "printMatrix" function will help you.

```
def printMatrix(matrix):
     for row in matrix:
             for element in row:
                     print str(element) + '\t',
             print

some_list = [[0, 0, 0.0, 17, 2], [0, 0, 0.0, 25, 2],\
             [0, 1, 0.017646, 11, 1], [0, 1, 0.028056, 10, 1],\
             [0, 1, 0.028056, 12, 1], [0, 1, 1.032746, 10, 0],\
             [0, 1, 1.032746, 12, 0], [0, 1, 1.091776, 11, 0]]
another_list = ["Digital Chanel", "State", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"]

printMatrix(some_list.insert(0,another_list))

Digital Chanel  State   Hour    Minute  Second  
0       0       0.0     17      2   
0       0       0.0     25      2   
0       1       0.017646        11      1   
0       1       0.028056        10      1   
0       1       0.028056        12      1   
0       1       1.032746        10      0   
0       1       1.032746        12      0   
0       1       1.091776        11      0
```

I have installed "pretty table" so let us have a go. In the end I am still not quite sure that we are on the same page, check my code:

```
import prettytable
newList = []       # empty list, to be filled with ROWS from PSOE_data
PSOE_data = some_list # see code above...

for row in PSOE_data: # loop through every row in PSOE_data
   if sum(row[0:3]) != 0: # if sum three first elements != 0
        #my note: why doesn't python care about type "int" or "float"?
        newList.append(row) # appends the entire row to newList

# at this stage "newList" is a list of lists: (is this what you want?)
# [[0, 1, 0.017646, 11, 1], 
#  [0, 1, 0.028056, 10, 1], 
#  [0, 1, 0.028056, 12, 1], 
#  [0, 1, 1.032746, 10, 0], 
#  [0, 1, 1.032746, 12, 0], 
#  [0, 1, 1.091776, 11, 0]]
PSOE_list = prettytable.PrettyTable(\
               ["Digital Chanel","State", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"])
PSOE_list.align["Digital Chanel"] = "c" 
PSOE_list.padding_width = 1 

# Note how it is useful to avoid "i,j,k" notation when looping through
# rows, i.e. when the counter is not an integer number. 

# this is what you are trying to do and it is doomed to fail because:
# row = [0, 1, 1.091776, 11, 0]
# PSOE_list.add_row([ newList[row][3], newList[row][4], newList[row][0], newList[row][1], newList[row][2] ])
# But if you do:
for row in newList:
    PSOE_list.add_row([ row[3], row[4], row[0], row[1], row[2] ])
# You get:
print PSOE_list
+----------------+-------+------+--------+----------+
| Digital Chanel | State | Hour | Minute |  Second  |
+----------------+-------+------+--------+----------+
|       11       |   1   |  0   |   1    | 0.017646 |
|       10       |   1   |  0   |   1    | 0.028056 |
|       12       |   1   |  0   |   1    | 0.028056 |
|       10       |   0   |  0   |   1    | 1.032746 |
|       12       |   0   |  0   |   1    | 1.032746 |
|       11       |   0   |  0   |   1    | 1.091776 |
+----------------+-------+------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: First of all, sorry for the lack of information! I want something like that, but the main point is that I don't know how many elements exist in the some_list, that is the reason for my for loop.
Following your ideia, my some_list is formed by every element from newList. I don't know if I was clear, sorry abot that!